# Joomla 3 Blog view with specified tags

Tags: view, joomla, tags, blogs, categories

Is it possible to show articles in blog view filtered by selected tags? I mean select tags from a module and show articles containing those tags in category blog view?

Answer (score 1):

You can go to tags in the component menu and create tags. After which you can add them to the particular articles that you choose.

You can then create menu items for the tags and the menu would filter it.

For some more reading take a look [here](https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:How_To_Use_Content_Tags_in_Joomla!)!

Comment: Thanks a lot. I created something like this demo:
http://j33a.freesite.host/index.php?option=com_tags&view=tag&id[0]=3&id[1]=5&types[0]=1&Itemid=142

but the problem is that it is just listing the articles. Not showing intro or images or author name etc. Like Joomla does in blog view. Can you help a bit more?

Comment: @I.Adam When I did this it showed up exactly the way your link is. Are you trying to get the author to list on the page that lists all available tags? If possible can you send me a link to the page you created to I could take a look.